# In Which Event I can Get The GCM response using PushSharp To send Notification To Android Devices?

Tags: c#, android, .net, pushsharp

I am Trying To send Notification From My .Net Server To all Android Devices Downloaded My Android Application. I am Using PushSharp library. Sending Notification is fine. But I am trying to get the response from GCM that tells me the  canonical registration IDs If the user uninstall the application and download it agian. I am having an issue of sending tow notification to same android device. One using the New ID and one Using unregistered ID I am trying to remove that ID from my database. So that I can send only one notification for single device. I ma registering these 4 events which are triggered By GCM.
In Which Event Can I do my Logic ?

Any Help is Appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
    private static void Events_OnNotificationSent(Notification notification)
    {

    }

    private static void Events_OnNotificationSendFailure(Notification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
    {

    } 



    private static void Events_OnChannelException(Exception exception, PlatformType platformType, Notification notification)
    {
    } 



    private static void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired(PlatformType platform, string deviceInfo, Notification notification)
    {

    } 



    private static void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged(PlatformType platform, string oldDeviceInfo, string newDeviceInfo, Notification notification)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove the device from your database if the user has uninstalled your app.  I'm using the following logic to do that for my project:

```
private void Events_OnNotificationFailed(object sender, INotification notification, Exception error)
{
    var gcmNotification = notification as GcmNotification;
    bool userHasUninstalled = error.Message.Contains("Device Subscription has Expired");
    bool isAndroidNotification = gcmNotification != null;
    if (isAndroidNotification && userHasUninstalled)
    {
        foreach (var registrationId in gcmNotification.RegistrationIds)
        {
            DeleteDeviceByIdentifier(registrationId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnak for you response. I got working in this event :   private static void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired(PlatformType platform, string deviceInfo, Notification notification)
    {

    }

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari: So, where do you get the canonical registration ID in `Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired`?

Comment: @marceln you mean how do I get it ?

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari: Yes, exactly.

Comment: By the time you are registering the event, pushBroker.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired; define the method in this way :                                          private static void OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired(object sender, string expiredDeviceSubscriptionId, DateTime timestamp, INotification notification) {        }   Then you have it as a string in the method body. You can call a DB function to remove it.

Comment: PushBroker class included in Push Sharp library.